# Defining an intersection using interface, not type

Tags: typescript

Given an intersection type like this:

```
type Combination = Type1 & Type2;
```

How can it be written using an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)?

This attempt doesn't compile:

```
interface Combination = Type1 & Type2;
```

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: It's not a need, but we typically prefer interfaces to types, hence seeing if I could make the conversion

Comment: For what it's worth, that rule probably comes from the Typescript constraint on literal object types not allowing excess properties whereas interfaces do allow them. That rule doesn't apply in this situation, though, as the intersection type is not a literal object type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Interfaces do not allow excess properties either

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Welp, I learned something new today. I could swear interfaces allowed it, but clearly it does not. Interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, in general. In theory, we could get it by extending the type

```
interface Combination extends (Type1 & Type2) {}
```

But the [language's grammar](https://github.com/frenchy64/typescript-parser/blob/master/typescript.ebnf) won't allow that. Only qualified identifiers (potentially with type arguments) can be used in an "extends" clause.

Note that we can use type aliases in an "extends" clause, so the following technically answers your question

```
type TemporaryName = Type1 & Type2
interface Combination extends TemporaryName {}
```

`Combination` is an interface that represents an intersection type. But that's a very mathematical and unhelpful answer, if your goal is to avoid using type aliases.

Answer (score 2):

Type union to interface can be translated into

```js
interface Type1 { name: string }
interface Type2 { id: number }
interface Combination extends Type1, Type2 {}
```